# Insert query inside for loop not working correctly

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I am working on Asp .Net project. So I have a page where I am generating random coupon keys. So user enters quantity and generate.

So what I did, I put a for loop according to quantity and inside the for loop I created a random key and search for the key in DB (key is unique) and then insert the data in DB.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
{
  do
  {
    couponKey = generateKey();
   } while (!SearchEpinKey(couponKey));

   conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
   conn.Open();

   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
   {
       cmd.Connection = conn;
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       string query = "INSERT INTO CouponStock (coupon_key,  status, created_on)";
       query += "VALUES('" + couponKey + "','Unused', GETDATE())";
       cmd.CommandText = query; 
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Inside the loop, Flow is like:

```
-Genrate random key
-Search if random key exists or not in db
-If found similar then again generate random key
-Insert the data in DB
```

So when I run this page for smaller quantities like 10 or 15, its working fine. But when I go for 50 or 100 its inserting random number of rows like sometime 24, sometime 48. And application get hangs after this. I am thinking that Sql server is hitting numerous time in short interval. Any guidance on how to handle this will be helpful.

Comment: What is the logic being used to generate your random key? You might be able to move this entire process to a stored procedure. It would be much simpler, faster and accurate.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the idea, I will put all the data in collection and then execute the query. I don't know about table valued parameter, but I will search on internet.

Comment: @SeanLange If I use the same logic inside procedure, will it work correctly?

Comment: Not if you are talking doing looping. You want to avoid looping as much as possible when it comes to data. I was thinking you could create a procedure that receives how many new keys to generate and do all the work in your procedure. You really should start working on separating your data and application layers. The code you posted indicates they are very tightly coupled.

Comment: Also you create a SQL connection, open it and close it inside your loop. Open it once before the loop and close if after the loop is done.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf If I dont close previous connection then insert query runs only one time. That's why I opened and closed.

Comment: @SeanLange I have one query, what about the unique key. In current code I am generating key and seaching in the db for similar key, if found that generating again and then inserting. If I make a collection, then hw can I handle that those collection of keys are remain unique? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes your current code is horribly inefficient. You generate a value, then query the database to see if it exists, then insert it. If you do this in the database you can do it all in one step. If you can share what your "key" looks like I can probably help.

Comment: @SeanLange Key is random string of 25 characters like this AS4ZSLNLKGX5NY2X4NM2SYEMG

Comment: Why not use a guid instead?

Comment: @SeanLange My main purpose is to generate a given number of random unique keys and save in DB that's all. If you have any simple query, it may help.

Comment: If you are stuck using a 25 character string then you are stuck. If you can change your datatype to uniqueidentifier (guid in .net) then this becomes really simple.

Comment: If your key is 25 characters long and random then don't bother checking for uniqueness. Unless there is a bug in your random character generator then the chance of generating two the same is so small it can be considered zero.

Comment: @AndyNichols This is 25 character key and I am also going to create new column which is md5 hash random generated password. So can I skip the unique check and just insert?

Comment: Yes. The number of possible keys is 36^25 assuming any alphanumeric character and assuming all values are equally likely. You won't get duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could find is because of this

```
do
{
  couponKey = generateKey();
} while (!SearchEpinKey(epinKey));
```

If you are using `couponKey` in your `INSERT` query, why do you use `SearchEpinKey(epinKey)`? where are you searching for `couponKey` in DB?

You are assigned `generateKey()` to `couponKey`  variable, and your are checking against `epinKey`, I believe that when `epinKey` is already stored in DB it hangs (an infinite loop), because `epinKey` is always the same even if you  assing a new value to `couponKey`

just change this line

```
} while (!SearchEpinKey(epinKey));
```

to this

```
} while (!SearchEpinKey(couponKey));
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I made the edit. but the problem is still same.

Comment: what is the code of the generateKey() function? Post it please

Comment: its just returning a random number of 25 chars, nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first I think we should avoid opening a new connection on every insert, also we should always use ASP.Net build in function for parameter (e.g. AddWithValue), as they help avoid [SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(SQL.105).aspx)

```cs
    var couponList  = new System.Collections.Generic.List<String>(); 
    var query = "INSERT INTO CouponStock(coupon_key, status, created_on) VALUES(@coupon_key, @status, GETUTCDATE());";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) 
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            do{
                var couponKey = generateKey();

                //return early for readability
                if(!SearchEpinKey(couponKey)) continue;
                if(couponList.Contains(couponKey)) continue;

                //add to coupon list to ensure newly generated key does not duplicate
                couponList.Add(couponKey);

                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(query);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coupon_key", couponKey);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Unused");

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            while (couponList.Count < quantity);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle exceptions or re-throw them...
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```